# Standard and "exotic" icons

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, icons

I'm trying to use the standard icons in Qt for a QToolButton but I have a problem. My code is:

```
m_buttonZoomPlus->setIcon(QStyle::standardIcon(QStyle::SP_DesktopIcon));
```

I get the error message :

> cannot call member function 'QIcon QStyle::standardIcon(QStyle::StandardPixmap, const QStyleOption*, const QWidget*) const' without object

What does it mean? Do I Have to create an empty QStyle object and call the standardIcon function on it?

Besides, I found a list of standard icons here: http://doc.trolltech.com/main-snapshot/qstyle.html#StandardPixmap-enum

Is this list exhaustive or are there other standard icons? I'm looking for instance for a zoom-in/out icon and I've not yet been able to find it.

Thank you very much for you help.

Comment: It sounds like `QStyle::standardIcon` is not a static member function and you have to do something like: `QStyle style; style.standardIcon(QStyle::SP_DesktopIcon);`

Comment: @bames53 I've done the following (I use QCommonStyle because QStyle is abstract): add `QIcon m_icon; QCommonStyle m_style;` in my class attribute, initialize like this: `m_style(), m_icon(m_style.standardIcon(QStyle::SP_DesktopIcon))` then use `m_buttonZoomPlus->setIcon(m_icon)`. I can now see the icon but when I clik on it the program crashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means `standardIcon` is not a static method so you can't call it that way. You need to construct a `QStyle` and initialize it appropriately then you can use that method to get a specific icon.

**Edit:** Jeremy is right. If you aren't changing the style or defining your own style you can simply use the following:

```
QApplication::style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_DesktopIcon);
```

Reference: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#standardIcon

Comment: I can't see your link because it's blocked but I've tried to initialize a QCommonStyle and use this but although I can now see the icon, the program crashes and I click on it. See the comment under the initial post. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Leo since you can see the icon now your question is answered. The crash when you click the button is probably something completely different and unrelated.

Comment: The Qt documentation is blocked? Ouch. Anyway, if it crashes when you click it we would need to see what slot you've connected to the mouse input for clicking and the error received to determine why that is happening. That would be a new question though probably ...

Comment: @bames53 @AJG85 the problem is that I delete the QIcon and just put the a text for instance then I can click the button and there is no problem whatsoever.
The slot is:
`QObject::connect(m_buttonZoomPlus, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(zoomPlus()));` 
And:
`void Graphique::zoomPlus()
{
    if (!m_fichier.isEmpty())
    {
        m_scale = m_scale*1.5;
        m_itemImage->setScale(m_scale);
        m_scene->setSceneRect(0, 0, m_scale*m_image->width(), m_scale*m_image->height());
    }

}`

Comment: Don't construct a QStyle object, use the same QStyle object QApplication is using.  E.g. qApp->style()->standardIcon(...);